# How report on data in columns by date in SQL (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I need to report my data with a column for each date. It's okay if I need to specify the dates ahead of time (i.e., I don't need to discover the dates from the data in the table), but each column has to have the data for just that date.

My source data is normalized, so each row has the data and the date.

For example,

```
create table test1 (
id int primary key,
name varchar(32),
created datetime default current_timestamp,
rows int
);
```

So test1 might have date in rows like

```
234 fred  2017-01-01  17
235 alice 2017-01-02  32
...
```

I'm looking for output that looks like this:

```
NAME       2017-01-01     2017-01-02    2017-01-02
fred           17              19           24
alice          29              32           64
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that works (there might be a better way, but this works) is:

```
select name
  , max(case when date(created) = '2017-12-01' then rows else 0 end) as '2017-12-01'
  , max(case when date(created) = '2017-12-02' then rows else 0 end) as '2017-12-02'
  , max(case when date(created) = '2017-12-03' then rows else 0 end) as '2017-12-03'
from test1
group by name;
```

The `case` puts the value of `created` into the right column by date, else it puts a zero; the `max` weeds out the zeros so the `group by` shows the desired values. If you don't `else 0`, you get NULLS and the NULLS overwhelm the values in the `group by` and it doesn't work correctly (voice of experience talking).